# What is wrong with my sudoku generate code in c?

Tags: c, sudoku

That's my homework, making a sudoku game. I have done my algorithm but it's entering infinite loop. I didn't understand why.

I am trying create a random number and control it for find true number. Checking all columns and rows for find same number as like as our random number if it is, it's changing test number and if test has changed trying find another number for true number. Simple sudoku logic.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  srand(time(NULL));
  int num, col, row, row2, col2, test = 0;
  int sudo[9][9] = {{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}};

  for (row = 0; row <= 8; row++) {
    for (col = 0; col <= 8; col++) {
      do {
        test = 0;
        num = rand() % 9 + 1;
        //control
        for (col2 = 0; col2 <= 8; col2++) {
          if (num == sudo[col2][row]) {
            test++;
          }
        }
        for (row2 = 0; row2 <= 8; row2++) {
          if (num == sudo[col][row2]) {
            test++;
          }
        }
      } while (test > 0);
      sudo[col][row] = num;
    }
  }
//print
  for (row = 0; row <= 8; row++) {
    for (col = 0; col <= 8; col++) {
      printf(" %d ", sudo[col][row]);
      if (col == 2 || col == 5) {
        printf(" | ");
      }
    }
    if (row == 2 || row == 5) {
      printf("\n---------------------------------");
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

Comment: Please, use {{0}} to init a 2D array. And specify `int main`.

Comment: If `test` is ever incremened, that loop will spin forever. So there's your problem.

Comment: its "debug me code" question

Comment: I added a `printf("%d\n", test);` before `while (test > 0);`.  It always (many iterations) printed non-zero.

Comment: i can't found any reason for that

Comment: What is code trying to do with the first `for (row = 0;...) { for (col = 0; ...) {` loops?  Build a board?

Comment: i use it for find a reference coordinate. I referenced it and tried find true number for this coordinate.

Comment: But it can't found true number for this coordinate without marked test. Do you have any solution for this ?

Comment: Even without bugs you might have reached an impossible solution. A linear approach might not work. Better strategy is to undo / rewind to a previous cell and try another number when there is no solution. A recursive approach might be better.

Comment: second for( row and col) looking for is there any same number at row and col. if it is retrying finding right number.

Comment: i am gonna try recursive finally but i am trying how to solve this problem with this algorithm.

Comment: If you want some practice you could try [this challenge](https://projecteuler.net/problem=96) ;-)

Comment: @WeatherVane I will but i dont have time for now. This homework have to done at sunday. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your algorithm is broken, and I can demonstrate why. If it were possible to fill in a sudoku puzzle this way, it would also be trivial to solve a sudoku puzzle this way, which it is not.

Essentially your code boils down to the following. I've added early exits on the inner for-loops to stop searching once we find the number already in the current row or column (and actually made sense of what 99.9% of the world thinks of concerning "rows" and "columns" in a NxN matrix):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define NSIZE 9

void print_matrix(int const ar[][NSIZE])
{
    for (size_t i=0; i<NSIZE; ++i)
    {
        for (size_t j=0; j<NSIZE; ++j)
        {
            fputc('0' + ar[i][j], stdout);
            fputc(' ', stdout);
        }
        fputc('\n', stdout);
    }
}

int main()
{
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    int sudo[NSIZE][NSIZE] = {{0}};
    int row, col;

    for(row=0;row<NSIZE;++row)
    {
        for(col=0;col<NSIZE;++col)
        {
            int row2 = 0, col2 = 0, num;
            printf("Trying ");
            do
            {
                num = rand()%9+1;
                printf("%d ", num);
                for(row2=0; row2<NSIZE && num!=sudo[row2][col]; ++row2);
                for(col2=0; col2<NSIZE && num!=sudo[row][col2]; ++col2);
            }
            while (row2 < NSIZE || col2 < NSIZE);
            fputc('\n', stdout);

            sudo[row][col] = num;
            printf("sudo[%d][%d] = %d\n", row, col, num);
            print_matrix(sudo);
        }
    }
}
```

As the loops progress, we report what number we're trying, and what the matrix looks like upon placement of a keeper. For example, a test run of the above initially can look like this:

```html
Trying 8 
sudo[0][0] = 8
8 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
Trying 1 
sudo[0][1] = 1
8 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
Trying 9 
sudo[0][2] = 9
8 1 9 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
Trying 6 
sudo[0][3] = 6
8 1 9 6 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
Trying 3 
sudo[0][4] = 3
8 1 9 6 3 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
Trying 4 
sudo[0][5] = 4
8 1 9 6 3 4 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
Trying 4 6 7 
sudo[0][6] = 7
8 1 9 6 3 4 7 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
Trying 1 3 1 3 4 1 3 8 4 9 3 8 1 4 7 9 3 8 8 8 4 9 6 5 
sudo[0][7] = 5
8 1 9 6 3 4 7 5 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

and this continues for perhaps a while. But eventually, unless you get extraordinarily lucky, the following is bound to happen (and this one went pretty deep before the wheels fell off):

```html
Trying 1 6 3 4 
sudo[6][6] = 4
8 1 9 6 3 4 7 5 2 
1 3 5 4 8 6 2 7 9 
3 6 4 8 7 9 5 2 1 
7 9 1 2 4 5 3 8 6 
4 7 3 9 2 8 6 1 5 
5 4 2 3 6 1 8 9 7 
6 8 7 1 9 3 4 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Note we're about to try and populate `sudo[6][7]`. To do that we must find a number that is not in the `sudo[r][7]` column already, nor the `sudo[6][c]` row. But looking at the numbers already in those positions.

```html
sudo[r][7] : {5,7,2,8,1,9}
sudo[6][c] : {6,8,7,1,9,3,4}
```

Therefore we're looking for a number from 1..9 that is NOT in: `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}`, which we're NEVER going to find.

The algorithm is broken. There is a reason backtracking is used for tasks like this.

Comment: I got it now. Thanks a lot of for help.

Comment: No problem. It seems like such a logical way to do this, until you do it =)